# ssh connection refused with out iptables rulles

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, connection

I changed the ssh port from 22 to 2021 and it worked correctly till 3hours ago,after that when I can't connect to ssh.

```
ssh: connect to host 130.185.72.125 port 2021: Connection refused
```

so I checked iptables,I stop it from webmin,and

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
where is the problem?

Comment: Is the SSH service still listening on that port?

Answer (score 4):

The sshd process may not be running at all.

try checking with:

```
netstat -tulpn  | grep LISTEN | grep sshd
```

to see if it's running, and on which port.

Comment: definitely what one would expect if there was nothing listening there... `$ ssh -p 12345 localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 12345: Connection refused`